# Preserve Regular Expression Characters in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a bunch of text documents that in some cases have words concatenated together in such a way that they sometimes appear like this: "ThreeWordsTogether"

I would in stead like them to appear like: "Three Words Together"

I attempted to use the gsub function to produce the desired string in this way:

```
gsub("[a-z][A-Z][a-z]", "[a-z] [A-Z][a-z]", "ThreeWordsTogether")
```

Which rather predictably returned: "Thre[a-z] [A-Z][a-z]rd[a-z] [A-Z][a-z]gether"

I did not see anything in the gsub documentation which would suggest you could preserve the characters captured by the regular expression "[a-z][A-Z][a-z]"

Is there a way of doing this in R, or is this one of the limitations of regular expression matching? (I'm rather new to this)

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is with the `snakecase` package:

```
snakecase::to_any_case("ThreeWordsTogether", case = "big_camel", sep_out = " ")
```

Comment: This is great; however, I noticed that the result of to_any_case("That's", case = "big_camel", sep_out = " ") is "That S". Is there any way to preserve "That's"? The closest thing the documentation offered was setting parsing_option=3, but that doesn't actually do what I want it to here. Cheers!

Comment: I think the `sep_in` option can be useful, but not exactly what you want:`to_any_case("That's", case = "big_camel", sep_in = "\b", sep_out = " ")` `"That'S"`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use capture groups, which are defined by `()` and referred to by `\1` and `\2` in the order that they appear in the pattern (you have to escape so it's actually two `\`). I use `stringr` but you can do this with `gsub` too. This basically says find a single lowercase letter followed by a capital letters, and return them with a space in between. Note that this will work for any number of words and leave existing words alone, but won't work for any words that happen to have capital letters in the middle for whatever reason. You will have to keep tweaking this to suit your circumstances - e.g right now it won't split if a word ends in a character that isn't a lowercase letter.

```r
library(stringr)
strings <- c("TwoWords", "ThreeWordsTogether", "Three Words Apart",
             "FourWordsTogetherHere", "MiDdleCaps")

strings %>%
  str_replace_all("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2")
#> [1] "Two Words"                "Three Words Together"    
#> [3] "Three Words Apart"        "Four Words Together Here"
#> [5] "Mi Ddle Caps"
```

Created on 2018-07-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is meant as a comment to the question regarding the snakecase solution. (I believe it is easier to read as a separate answer.) So in order to suppress the uppercase conversion of the "s" in "That's" using the [snakecase-pkg](https://github.com/Tazinho/snakecase) and answer the original question one has mainly two options.

Both require to set `sep_in` to sth. different than its default (`"[^[:alnum:]]"`), e.g. `sep_in = NULL`, to not treat `'` an input separator (and therefore replace it by an "_").

The first option then uses `parsing_option = -1`. Adding a minus to a `parsing_option` generally suppresses triggering of case conversion after non-alphanumeric characters within the snakecase pkg.

```r
strings <- c("TwoWords", "ThreeWordsTogether", "Three Words Apart",
             "FourWordsTogetherHere", "MiDdleCaps", "That's")

snakecase::to_upper_camel_case(
  strings, sep_in = NULL, parsing_option = -1, sep_out = " "
)
#> [1] "Two Words"                "Three Words Together"    
#> [3] "Three Words Apart"        "Four Words Together Here"
#> [5] "Mi Ddle Caps"             "That's"
```

The other option uses `snakecase::to_title_case()` which internally combines some parts from `snakecase::to_sentence_case()` with `tools::toTitleCase()` (i.e. "That's" gets first converted into "that ' s" before  `tools::toTitleCase()` is applied and the spaces around `'` are removed).

```r
snakecase::to_title_case(strings, sep_in = NULL)
#> [1] "Two Words"                "Three Words Together"    
#> [3] "Three Words Apart"        "Four Words Together Here"
#> [5] "Mi Ddle Caps"             "That's"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>